# SQL & Ruby combo - looping through nested results

Tags: sql, ruby, loops

I'm working on some SQL exercises.  I have tables full of candidate names & voter info,  I've pulled up the voters for each candidate and am trying to print out "candidate: list of names." My code currently prints the first 2 voters on the list.  I've tried writing in loops after name like *first.times do*, etc. but I can't figure out how to get all the voter names to print. Any advice?

```
def print_not_so_secret_ballot
  puts "Candidate & Voter names"
  the_list = $db.execute("SELECT congress_members.name, voters.first_name, voters.last_name FROM (congress_members INNER JOIN votes ON congress_members.id = votes.politician_id) INNER JOIN voters ON votes.voter_id = voters.id GROUP BY congress_members.name")

the_list.each do |name, first, last|
    puts "#{name}: #{first} #{last}, #{first} #{last}, "
  end
```

Comment: shouldn't last code be like: `the_list.each{|list| puts "#{list.name}: #{list.first} #{list.last_name}" }`. Also, have you tried running that query in your SQL console to see how many records are being fetched?

Comment: Oddly when I do *puts "#{list.name}: #{list.first} #{list.last_name}, " }* only the first voter name prints out.  Each candidate has several hundred names as results.

Comment: Like I said, have you tried running your SQL script in your SQL console to see how many entries and what sort of data is being fetched?

Comment: I also run the code and see one candidate name, one first_name, and one last_name.  There should be hundreds of first & lasts after each candidate name.

Comment: Can you post the data of `the_list` variable from your code?